# How to get more search data using binary search?

Tags: java, arrays, search, indexing

First of all I apologize for my english and this is my first time asking on stackoverflow so if i miss something please point it out.

So I'm new to java and trying out binary search with the help from my friend. The code is to display product information once searched with product ID. I manage to make it return the index number where Id is found but the problem is when i put in multiple same ID it only show 1 data. I want my program to show all the index where the ID-12 is found.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class MyListBinarySearch {

public static void main(String a[]){

    List<Emp> empList = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    empList.add(new Emp(12,"Apple,50,10-5-2014"));
    empList.add(new Emp(12,"Apple,50,5-5-2014"));
    empList.add(new Emp(124,"Apple,50,2-5-2014"));
    empList.add(new Emp(302,"Apple,50,2-5-2014"));
    empList.add(new Emp(12,"Apple,50,2-5-2014"));

    Emp searchKey = new Emp(12,"String");
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(empList, searchKey, new EmpComp());
    System.out.println("Index of the searched key: "+index);
}
}

class EmpComp implements Comparator<Emp>{

public int compare(Emp e1, Emp e2) {
    if(e1.getEmpId() == e2.getEmpId()){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}

class Emp {

private int empId;
private String empInfo;


public Emp(int id, String info){
    this.empId = id;
    this.empInfo = info;

}

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public String getEmpInfo() {
    return empInfo;
}

public void setEmpInfo(String empInfo) {
    this.empInfo = empInfo;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return empId+" : "+empInfo;
}
}
```

The out is "Index of searched key: 2" 
I want to display all the index where the search key is found.
How do i do that ? Do i need to loop ?

Comment: Let me understand: you want to do a binary search where there are multiple right answers, and you want to return all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Your comparator should return something greater than 0 when the current element is greater than the compared element, 0 when the elements are *equals* and less than 0 when the current element is less than the compared element. Your current implementation doesn't cover this.
2. Binary search works on sorted arrays/lists only. Your list is not sorted by id.

After fixing this issues, then you will effectively use binary search. After retrieving the index where the element is 12, you can search around the element to retrieve all the elements that have the same Id.

This is an idea how to implement it:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(empList, searchKey, new EmpComp());
List<Emp> empsWithId12 = new ArrayList<Emp>();
for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Emp emp = empList.get(i);
    if (emp.getId() == 12) {
        empsWithId12.add(emp);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
Collections.reverse(empsWithId12);
for (int i = index; i < empList.size(); i++) {
    Emp emp = empList.get(i);
    if (emp.getId() == 12) {
        empsWithId12.add(emp);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that the idea above can be greatly improved by moving the logic into a method.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the index of the the search key, you can go backwards or left of the list to find all other indexes with key equal to the search key